# Counting matchings on 3-regular bipartite graphs

Tags: counting-complexity, matching, bipartite-graphs

What I call a graph here allows parallel edges.
Is the following problem #P-hard:

**INPUT**: a 3-[regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) graph $G$

**OUTPUT**: the number of [matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) of $G$.

It is known that counting matchings on 2-3-regular (even planar) graphs is #P-hard: in [this paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/papers/interpolation08.pdf) it corresponds to the problem denoted $\#[1,1,0]|[1,1,0,0]$, which is hard according to the table page 10, and in [that one](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82063901.pdf) it corresponds to the problem $\#$2-3-RBP-$\lambda$-Matchings with $\lambda = 1$, and it is also shown to be #P-hard. In that last paper it is also shown that counting matchings on $3$-regular planar graphs is hard (see page 122, second paragraph). But what I need is 3-regular bipartite graphs.

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because it's a different problem, but the #P-completeness of counting *perfect* matchings in 3-regular bipartite graphs is proved in

P. Dagum and M. Luby. Approximating the permanent of graphs with large factors. Theoretical Computer Science 102(2):283–305, 1992, doi:10.1016/0304-3975(92)90234-7.